# How to pass data from Child to Parent: Angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm following the docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent

However so far not able to get a string variable from the child into the parent.

---

### The Child

#### Here I'm sending the category title to the emitter

```
import { Component,
         ChangeDetectionStrategy,
         EventEmitter,
         Output,
         OnInit,
         ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
    selector: 'category',
    styleUrls: [ './category.component.css' ],
    templateUrl: './category.component.html'
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string = '';
    @Output() onCategoryTitled = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.title = this.route.snapshot.params['title'];
        console.log('this.title', this.title)
        this.onCategoryTitled.emit(this.title);
    }
}
```

### The Parent app.component

#### Here is the parent, I'm able to see the log from the child, but not the log here

```
import { Component,
         Directive,
         ElementRef,
         Renderer,
         ChangeDetectionStrategy,
         OnInit,
         ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    catTitle:string;

    onCategoryTitled(cat_title: string) {
        console.log('EVENT recieved cat_title:', cat_title)
        this.catTitle = cat_title;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('AppComponent init')
    }
}
```

#### Parent markup (Where I need the title)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 h20"></div></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="/wiki">Home</a></li>
                <li>{{ catTitle }}</li>
                <!-- <li><a href="/wiki/category">Categories</a></li> -->
            </ol>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <footer class="container col-sm-12">
        <p>©2017 <strong>WikiTags</strong>
    </footer>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add `app.component.html` I suppose you have there something like this `<category (onCategoryTitled)="onCategoryTitled($event)"></category> `

Comment: @yurzui just added the markup, the 2nd `li` is where I'm trying to display the `title`. Also I just updated my code, added the `catTitle` model variable for the Parent app.component markup.

Comment: Where is your CategoryComponent in the Parent? Is it inside the `router-outlet`? If so, you'll need to create a service to communicate the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method of communication that you're attempting from [The Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent) is to be used when the Child is nested directly in the Parent.  In that case, on the Parent you would bind your event handler to the emitted event like in their example:

`(onVoted)="onVoted($event)"`

Your case is a bit different because you have `router-outlet` that dynamically loads the component into the parent, and that introduces a bit more complexity.  You still need to bind (or subscribe) to the event, but (as you may have encountered) you *can't* add the binding directly to the `router-outlet` as that simpler cookbook example shows. You *can*, however, introduce an "intermediary" service that can communicate the event for you across the `router-outlet` boundary.

For Example, you could write some sort of "communication" service as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyCommunicationService {

    constructor() { }

    private emitChangeSource = new Subject<any>();

    changeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

    // Service message
    emitChange(myMessage: any) {
        this.emitChangeSource.next(myMessage);
    }

}
```

Emit the event from your child component:

```
...
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _myCommunicationService: MyCommunicationService) {}

    doSomething(): void {
        ...
        // Emit your event with message
        this._myCommunicationService.emitChange('some change');
    }
...
```

Then listen for (subscribe to) the event in the parent component (in your case app.component) that contains the `router-outlet`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _myCommunicationService: MyCommunicationService) {

        // Subscribe to the service event
        _myCommunicationService.changeEmitted$.subscribe(myMessage => {
            // TODO: Do what you need to to with the message/value
            ...
        });

    }
}
```

Let me know if this needs clarification. (I could have also totally missed the boat and *assumed* that the Child Component is loading within the `router-outlet` when in reality you're doing something entirely different.)

**Note:** This is untested code.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out soon, bogged down atm. In your opinion would it be better to redesign the app so that wiki will be the parent containing the category page's markup? Or is the service superior? In matters of state management.

Comment: @LeonGaban My opinion is relatively inconsequential as I really don't know your requirements. ;) Personally, knowing only what little I know about your requirements and assuming there isn't some hidden complexity, I would try to refactor it like you mentioned -- Wiki being the parent of Category -- if only to eliminate the unneeded complexity.